# Jenkins Pipeline: "input" step blocks executor

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

After going through the [pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline) and [Jenkinsfile](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/jenkinsfile/) documentation, I am a bit confused on how to create a *Stage -> Production* pipeline.

One way is to use the `input` step like

```java
node() {
  stage 'Build to Stage'
  sh '# ...'

  input 'Deploy to Production'
  stage 'Build to Production'
  sh '# ...'
}
```

This seems a bit clunky, as this will block an executor all the time until you want to deploy to production. Is there any alternative way of being able to deploy to production, from Jenkins.

Comment: I took the chance to update the question title from "Create Stage and Prod pipelines with Jenkins" to a more descriptive one.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

EDIT (Oct 2016): Please see my other answer ["Use milestone and lock"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37831386/jenkins-pipeline-input-step-blocks-executor/40185898#40185898) below, which includes recently introduced features.

## Use `timeout` Step

As first option, you can wrap your `sh` step into a [`timeout`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-timeout-code-enforce-time-limit) step.

```java
node() {
  stage 'Build to Stage' {
    sh '# ...'
  }

  stage 'Promotion' {
    timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS') {
      input 'Deploy to Production?'
    }
  }

  stage 'Deploy to Production' {
    sh '# ...'
  }
}
```

This stops the build after the timeout.

## Move `input` Step to Flyweight Executor

Another option is to not allocate a heavyweight executor for the `input` step. You can do this by using the `input` step outside of the `node` block, like this:

```java
stage 'Build to Stage' {
  node {
      sh "echo building"
      stash 'complete-workspace'
  }
}

stage 'Promotion' {
  input 'Deploy to Production?'
}

stage 'Deploy to Production' {
  node {
    unstash 'complete-workspace'
    sh "echo deploying"
  }
}
```

This <strike>is</strike> [was](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37831386/jenkins-pipeline-input-step-blocks-executor/40185898#40185898) probably the more elegant way, but can still be combined with the `timeout` step.

EDIT: As pointed out by @amuniz, you have to stash/unstash the contents of the workspace, as different nodes respectively workspace directories might be allocated for the two `node` steps.

Comment: ..and as described by @amuniz, you want to include [stash/unstash](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-stash-code-stash-some-files-to-be-used-later-in-the-build) steps to copy with a different node/executor taking over the second node block.

Comment: @StephenKing, could you please explain on what resources will be consumed by a blocked flyweight executor? I tried above block of code; still see executors blocked in the left panel in the web console.

Comment: See the [link](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#pausing-flyweight-vs-heavyweight-executors) I already posted above: _a flyweight executor — an uncounted slot that is assumed to not take any significant computational power._

Comment: Can input be combined with a when condition? i.e. only prompt when the branch is 'master' for example

Answer (score 35):

Given the recent advances of Jenkins pipelines, the probably best way would be the following (source: [jenkins.io/blog](https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/10/16/stage-lock-milestone/)):

### Use `milestone` and `lock`

- The [`lock`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/lockable-resources/#code-lock-code-lock-shared-resource) step (from the [lockable-resources](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Lockable+Resources+Plugin) plugin) allows to lock some specified resource so that only a single pipeline execution can enter this stage simultaneously (you don't want to run two deployments simultaneously, do you?)
- The [`milestone`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-milestone-step/#code-milestone-code-the-milestone-step-forces-all-builds-to-go-through-in-order) step (from the [pipeline-milestone-step](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Milestone+Step+Plugin) plugin) will abort any older pipeline executions, if a more recent build already reached the milestone (you don't want to let an older build that hangs longer in CI overwrite the deployment of a newer build, do you?).

```java
stage('Deploy') {
  input "Deploy?"
  milestone()
  lock('Deployment') {
    node {
      echo "Deploying"
    }
  }
}
```

> The Deploy stage does not limit concurrency but requires manual input
>   from a user. Several builds might reach this step waiting for input.
>   When a user promotes a specific build all preceding builds are aborted,
>   ensuring that the latest code is always deployed.

I recommend to read [the whole story](https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/10/16/stage-lock-milestone/), which includes further helpful information.

Credits go to [@amuniz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1103811/amuniz), who is maintaining these plugins.

Comment: I believe you need to insert a milestone step before the input step as well.

Comment: Depends on the behavior that you want to implement.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I was assuming the use case included the need to abort older pipelines waiting at the same input step when a newer pipeline is allowed to proceed.

Comment: Using `milestone` and `lock` alone do not solve the OP's problem of blocking an executor though, right?  The key here still seems to be for the `input` step to be defined outside the `node` block.  `milestone` and `lock` are just preventing multiple builds from proceeding to the Deploying action.

Comment: Please ask a new question.

Comment: "but requires manual input from a user". Are you saying that you can't use the jenkns rest api to complete the INPUT step?

Answer (score 13):

You have to use the input step outside any node block, so it does not hold any executor:

```
stage 'Build'
node('build-node') {
  sh 'call you build tool'
  stash includes: 'target/my-output-artifact.whatever', name: 'built'
}

input 'Continue to deploy stage?'

stage 'Deploy'
node('deploy-node') {
  unstash 'built'
  sh 'scp target/my-output-artifact.whatever user@deploy-server:/deploy'
}
```

And you can lock the deploy stage if you want only one deploy at time:

```
lock ('deploy-server') {
  stage 'Deploy'
  node('deploy-node') {
    unstash 'built'
    sh 'scp target/my-output-artifact.whatever user@deploy-server:/deploy'
  }
}
```

Note that the key part here is the `stash` step as you can *move* artifacts from one node to another (you could share the same node for both actions but the workspace is not granted to be untouched between the two node calls, specially if some time passes waiting on `input`).

Comment: How does this work with the declarative pipeline syntax?