# How to run downstream job conditionally based on a parameter in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Following on from my question [How to trigger parameterized build on successful build in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41521287/how-to-trigger-parameterized-build-on-successful-build-in-jenkins)

I would like the invoke a downstream project but only if a boolean parameter is set to true. Is this possible? My pipeline looks like this:

```
node {
    try {
        echo "ConfigFilePath: ${ConfigFilePath}"
        echo "Delete VM on Successful Build: ${DeleteOnSuccess}"

        stage('checkout') {
            deleteDir()
            git 'http://my.git.lab/repo.git'
        }   

        stage('deploy') {
                bat 'powershell -nologo -file BuildMyVM.ps1 -ConfigFilePath "%ConfigFilePath%" -Verbose'                
            }
        }
        stage('test') {
            // functional tests go here
        }    
    } 
    catch (e) {
    // exception code

  } finally {
    // finally code

  }
} //node

stage('delete') {
    if(DeleteOnSuccess)
    {
        bat 'SET /p VM_NAME=<DeleteVM.txt'
        echo "Deleting VM_NAME: %VM_NAME%"
        def job = build job: 'remove-vm', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'VM_NAME', value: '${VM_NAME}']]
    }
}
```

I get this error on the delete stage

`Required context class hudson.FilePath is missing. 
Perhaps you forgot to surround the code with a step that provides this, such as: node`

If I wrap the above in a node, then the parameter values are lost. If I put the delete stage in the main node, then I take up two executors, which I'm trying to avoid because it will result in some deadlock conditions.

Comment: The error you get is about the `bat` you are trying to run. This requires a node (or actually a environment) as well. So depending on how you invoke your build in the first place,  you need to surround that with `node {...}` as wel, or just put it inside the `node` block as well.
If you only want to trigger it, and not wait for the build, you can add `wait: false` to the  `build` command.

Comment: OK, if I remove the `bat` and the `echo` lines, the job in the `delete` stage executes whether the project parameter `DeleteOnSuccess` is set to true or false. Any ideas why?

Comment: Is it perhaps a string. Not a boolean?

Comment: @Rik Definitely boolean https://i.imgur.com/ubsAvke.png

Comment: I think it is a string. Try echoing `DeleteONSuccess.class` in your pipeline script

Comment: You're right! `[Pipeline] echo
class java.lang.String` I've now re-written the conditional as `if(DeleteOnSuccess=="true")` and it works. Do you want to write as answer and I'll accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the running of a script actually needs a node to run on, so in your case the cause of the error is that you try to run a `bat` command outside of a `node` context

```
node {
...
}
stage('delete') {
    if(DeleteOnSuccess)
    {
        bat 'SET /p VM_NAME=<DeleteVM.txt' // <- this is actually causing the error
        echo "Deleting VM_NAME: %VM_NAME%"
        def job = build job: 'remove-vm', parameters: [[$class:    'StringParameterValue', name: 'VM_NAME', value: '${VM_NAME}']]
    }
}
```

You can fix this by wrapping this part also inside a node by either putting it inside the first `node` or add a new one, depending on what you want

Besides that, if the `DeleteOnSuccess` variable is a build parameter, it will be a string. I am not sure, but I think this is because it is injected as an environment variable, which are also strings (even if it is of type BooleanParameter. I guess that is only a UI thing so it will show up as checkbox).
You can check that by echoing `DeleteOnSuccess.class`. This will tell you its class

```
 if(DeleteOnSuccess) { ... }
```

will always run the conditional block. You can fix this by either converting it to a `bool` using the `toBoolean()` extension method, or checking it against the the string `true`: `DeleteOnSuccess == "true"`, like you did. 
The extension method has the advantage that it will also allow values `"1"` and `"True"` as `true`