# Queue jobs after input step using lock plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

We are using the [Lockable Resource Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Lockable+Resources+Plugin) to prevent certain parts of our jobs from running simultaneously.  I'd like to allow a job to start and gather input parameters using the "Input Step" then queue while waiting for any blocking locks to clear, then proceed.  Instead, I see the whole job blocking and not allowing me to enter input until all locks are cleared even though I have the Input Step outside of the Lock block.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is an example:

```
// Define an input step and capture the outcome from it.
def outcome = input id: 'deployment',
  message: 'Deployment Configuration',
  ok: 'Deploy',
  parameters: [
    [
      $class     : 'hudson.model.ChoiceParameterDefinition', choices: "development",
      name       : 'stack',
      description: 'select a stack to deploy'
    ],
    [
      $class     : 'hudson.model.ChoiceParameterDefinition', choices: "choice1\nchoice2",
      name       : 'profile',
      description: 'select a profile to deploy'
    ],
  ]

def profile = "${outcome.get('profile')}"
def stack = "${outcome.get('stack')}"

echo "profile: ${profile}"
echo "stack: ${stack}"

// use lockable resource to prevent multiple jobs of the same project from running at the same time.
lock(resource: "deployment") {
    sh "echo running deployment script here."
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following this post [Jenkins Pipeline: “input” step blocks executor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37831386/jenkins-pipeline-input-step-blocks-executor?rq=1)
I was able to solve the problem by adding

```
stage('deploy') {
}
```

around my block.  For example.

```
// Define an input step and capture the outcome from it.
def outcome = input id: 'deployment',
  message: 'Deployment Configuration',
  ok: 'Deploy',
  parameters: [
    [
      $class     : 'hudson.model.ChoiceParameterDefinition', choices: "development",
      name       : 'stack',
      description: 'select a stack to deploy'
    ],
    [
      $class     : 'hudson.model.ChoiceParameterDefinition', choices: "choice1\nchoice2",
      name       : 'profile',
      description: 'select a profile to deploy'
    ],
  ]

def profile = "${outcome.get('profile')}"
def stack = "${outcome.get('stack')}"

stage('deploy') {
  echo "profile: ${profile}"
  echo "stack: ${stack}"

  // use lockable resource to prevent multiple jobs of the same project from running at the same time.
  lock(resource: "deployment") {
    sh "echo running deployment script here."
  }
}
```