# Jenkins:Pipeline optional manual stage, that does not block any agent

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

Imagine a *multibranch* pipeline, that has stages **deploy**, **test**, **publish**

The scenario:

- Run build
- Build finishes, but stages like **publish** are not executed
- Someone goes to some completed build and triggers the **deploy** or **publish** stage
- This triggers continuation of the pipeline. on the same build

This will be much more convenient and user-friendly then running some other job with a Run Parameter. And it will keep the branch integrity.

Is there a way to do such magic with Jenkins pipeline multibranch?

Answer (score 2):

Make use of pipeline input step which allows the user to interact and control the flow of the build. Only a basic "process" or "abort" option is provided in the stage view.[Pipeline: Input Step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/)

Updating the post after the comments of aershov. Thanks to him.

Pipeline input step blocks the executor (i.e) it will be running state. Just noticed detailed answer regarding input step and milestone and locks are available @ [Jenkins Pipeline: "input" step blocks executor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37831386/jenkins-pipeline-input-step-blocks-executor)