# Is there any alternative for promoted builds in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Jenkins pipeline scripts for all my jobs. I was using Promoted-builds plugin for other jobs, But its not compatible with Pipeline scripts. Is there any alternative? .

Pipeline script has manual input but that does not solve the problem as the job is in build queue until the input is provided.

Comment: is the problem with `input` that it takes up an executor? if so, https://stackoverflow.com/q/37831386/6090676.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Hudson / Jenkins since 2007. I have never found the Promoted Builds plugin to be that useful.

Instead I use labels / tags from different jobs (Build and Unit Test, System Test, Performance Test) or artifact repositories as markers of where an version or artifact has progressed to in the overall "pipeline".

Regarding Artifactory:
In my Build and Unit Test job, on Success of the Integration branch I tag the source code and upload the tested artifact to Artifactory.

In my System Test job, on success I call my Performance Test job as a downstream job passing the version number of the successfully tested package as a parameter.

In my Performance Test job, on success I "copy-promote" the tested artifact to the next designated location in Artifactory.

HTH